# header hide on scroll - delay on scroll up

Tags: javascript

I want to add a delay to this header when the **user scrolls 200px up**: https://codepen.io/iabhinavr/pen/BaKxvRx

If see the codepen, right now it **only delays on scrolls down.**

This is what I have tried:

```
// menu hide on scroll 
(function(){

    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var w   = window;

    var curScroll;
    var prevScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
    var curDirection = 0;
    var prevDirection = 0;

    var header = document.getElementById('site-header');
    var toggled;
    var threshold = 350;
    var thresholdScrollUp = 200;

    var checkScroll = function() {
        curScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
        curScrollBottom = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
        if(curScroll > prevScroll) {
            // scrolled down
            curDirection = 2;
        }
        else {
            //scrolled up
            curDirection = 1;
        }

        if(curDirection !== prevDirection) {
            toggled = toggleHeader();
        }

        prevScroll = curScroll;
        if(toggled) {
            prevDirection = curDirection;
        }
    };

    var toggleHeader = function() { 
        toggled = true;
        if(curDirection === 2 && curScroll > threshold) {
            header.classList.add('hide');
            jQuery('#site-header-sticky-wrapper').addClass('hide');
        }
        else if (curDirection === 1 && curScrollBottom > thresholdScrollUp) {
            jQuery('#site-header-sticky-wrapper').removeClass('hide');
            header.classList.remove('hide');
        }
        else {
            toggled = false;
        }
        return toggled;
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);

})();
```

I added:

```
var thresholdScrollUp = 200;
```

and changed:

```
else if (curDirection === 1)
```

to:

```
else if (curDirection === 1 && curScrollBottom > thresholdScrollUp)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided code pen code work differently. Checkout this one

```
(function(){

    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var w   = window;

    var curScroll;
    var prevScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
    var curDirection = 0;
    var prevDirection = 0;
  
    var lastY = 0;

    var header = document.getElementById('site-header');
    var toggled;
    var threshold = 200;

    var checkScroll = function() {
        curScroll = w.scrollY || doc.scrollTop;
        if(curScroll > prevScroll) {
            // scrolled down
            curDirection = 2;
        }
        else {
            //scrolled up
            curDirection = 1;
        }

        if(curDirection !== prevDirection) {
            toggled = toggleHeader();
        } else {
            lastY=curScroll
        }

        prevScroll = curScroll;
        if(toggled) {
            prevDirection = curDirection;
        }
    };

    var toggleHeader = function() { 
        toggled = true;
        if(curDirection === 2 && (curScroll-lastY) > threshold) {
            lastY=curScroll
            header.classList.add('hide');
        }
        else if (curDirection === 1 && (lastY-curScroll) > threshold) {
            lastY=curScroll
            header.classList.remove('hide');
        }
        else {
            toggled = false;
        }
        return toggled;
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);

})();
```

Comment: thank you, I tried it but I see no difference. I also want to have a difference between the `threshold` (delay) of the scroll up and scroll down appearance of menu.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/RwVgqJa check this one. If your need is different, please clarify it